# Xcode's 'po' fails to identify the variable I wish to study. Why?

Tags: debugging, swift, xcode6

Environment: Xcode 6 Beta 4 
I'm attempting to merely look into a text value using
the debugger.  However the debugger fails to identify the static variable (via 'Let').  This is also true for vars.

Why?

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField:UITextField) -> Bool {
    let myText = "Hello World"
    let theText = textField.text! as String
    return true
}
```

Here's the debugger result:

> (lldb) po textField error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved
>   identifier 'textField' textField ^ :11:5: error: use of
>   unresolved identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
>       $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_29(
>       ^ (lldb) po myText error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'myText' myText ^ :11:5: error: use of unresolved
>   identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
>       $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_30(
>       ^ (lldb) po theText error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'theText' theText ^ :11:5: error: use of unresolved
>   identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
>       $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_31(
>       ^ (lldb)

Note: debug output is set to 'All Output.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you stopped at a breakpoint inside that function when you try this?

Comment: The breakpoint is within the function().

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure. Given that, I unfortunately have no clue what's wrong. But now it's a well-formed question, +1.

Comment: The code works...able to process the text.  However the DEBUGGER sucks.

Comment: I suspect that the debugger is not too Swift.  Partly, it's confused by `var` and `let`, I suspect, and it may not be able to locate `this` in the other case.

Comment: It seams like Xcode does a constant optimisation.
It work when I use `var myText = "Hello World"`
Also you don't use this constant in your method, so Xcode could just remove it from assembly code.

Comment: Xcode does a much better job debugging with ObjectiveC, in case you like that also.

Answer (score 15):

This is a problem I also encountered, and I think it is a bug in the debugger. If you do not use ANY variables declared with 'let', the po command will work. This is off course not what you want so I filed a bug with Apple for this issue.

I think you should just hope it is fixed in the next beta (file a bug too please, as number of filed bugs will influence Apple's priority in fixing them). In the meantime, go with Amitays workaround.

Comment: This is definitely a Swift-related problem.  The Objective-C version works.  So I've filed a bug with Apple: Report #17823710.

Comment: Xcode 8.2.1 still have the issue. it seems they don't have any plan to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed by others above, this is pretty much strictly a bug in Swift / LLDB.  It was mostly working as of 6.1.1, broken for or before 6.3 Beta 1, and fixed again in 6.3 Beta 2.

I am just using a command line app as a test and can't test with UIKit, but I have seen similar problems outside of UIKit - and by problems, I mean that I got results like the OP, but now it is working:

```
struct Foobar {
    var foo:String
    var bar:String
}

func textFieldShouldReturn() -> Bool {
    let fubar = Foobar(foo: "Onesy", bar: "Twosy")
    let myText = "Hello World"
    return true
}

textFieldShouldReturn()
```

p and po yield slightly different results, and depend on whether or not Printable is implemented:

```
(lldb) po fubar
(foo = "Onesy", bar = "Twosy")

(lldb) p fubar
(AssertClientMacDirect.Foobar) $R1 = (foo = "Onesy", bar = "Twosy")
```

Per the thread here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1111705#1111705, you can also use the `image lookup -t <SymbolName>` command

```
image lookup -t Fubar

<path redacted>
id = {0x1000003e0}, name = "AssertMac.Fubar", byte-size = 8, clang_type = "class Fubar {
class func `new`(name: Swift.String) -> AssertMac.Fubar
init(name: Swift.String)
func test()
var someValue: Swift.String
var name: Swift.String
@objc deinit
}
```

It is worth emphasizing though, that you should double check that the Swift compiler is set to:

- Debug / Optimization -> None,
- Strip Symbols on Copy -> NO,
- Link Time Optimization -> No
- Strip Symbols on Install -> NO, (for debug builds, where appropriate)

If you implement Printable on a swift class, then you will get the results of the description property.

There were previous Xcode bugs where Xcode would crash when trying to step through optimized code.