# Swift Debugging in Xcode: variables in the debug area are missed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, lldb

At some point, I have been facing a weird behavior while debugging the swift code. When I handle a breakpoint, the variables in the debug area are empty.

For example:

[image: debug]

If I try to print `self`, for example, I'm getting the following message:

```
Printing description of self:
self = <Unable to determine byte size.>
```

Overall it looks like I'm in the release mode, however I've double checked the configuration and seems it's ok:

- Current scheme has a debug configuration.
- Optimization level is None

Xcode 6.4

**UPDATE:** 
Debugging `objc` code in the same project works well.

**UPDATE 2:** 
I had migrated to Xcode 7 and swift 2.0 and the issue was fixed, but suddenly, I've got the same problem.

I've come across a discussion about a similar issue:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/xcode-7-debugger/50792

Comment: @ILikeTau tried — same here.

Comment: Looks like it might be an existing bug. This guy says he filed a bug report. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979939/4475605

Comment: @AdrianB Yeah, I thought that it might be a bug, but if I compile and run another project it works well.

Comment: Same issue from time to time

Comment: I'd say you've answered your own question. I suggest you should delete the update 2 from the question and give it as an answer! In a couple of days you can even accept your own answer and thus it will be Case Closed. :)